# Trouble with passing valid variables to query

Tags: php, mysql, variables, mysqli

I'm passing variables to my page `page?title=fred` but I would like to redirect to another page if it's the wrong value(not in the database) ex: `fredd`

The first part checks if the variable is empty. Which seems to be working.

```
//get variable from title
if(!isset($_GET['title']) || empty($_GET['title'])) {
    echo "no variable";
} 
else {
    $get_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['title']);
    $title = str_replace("-"," ", $get_title);
}
```

I'm having trouble checking if the variable I pass is in the database and if it's not to redirect to main page.

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT title FROM persons WHERE title = '$title'");
//check that variable is in the database
if(!isset($query)){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

    echo $row['title'];

  }
// mysqli_free_result($query);
} 
else {echo "variable does not exist";} ?>
```

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it? Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!isset($query)){
```

`$query` is always set (you just set it) so the code you want will never execute.

You want this instead:

```
if (!$query) {
  echo "Query returned error";
} else if (mysqli_num_rows($query) < 1) {
  echo "Variable does not exist";
} else {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo $row['title'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

isset($query) will ALWAYS be true - mysqli_query() will always returning SOMETHING, even if it's just a boolean false value.

```
$result = mysqli_query(..);
if ($result === false) {
    die(mysqli_error());
}
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   echo "variable does not exist";
} else {
   while(...) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Genuine question, not sarky comment: Do you need to do `$result === false` for a function that returns either a resource or a boolean? It was my understanding that any resource, regardless of status, will always evaluate to `true` if tested directly as a boolean.

Comment: It's a good habit to get into. While in this case, yeah, it's overkill, in other places (strpos is a particularly nasty one) it's utterly vital.

Comment: Fair enough, can't argue with that. I tend to do it anyway because I have been brow-beaten into the habit by JSLint and that has carried over into my PHP, but I just wondered if there was a reason other than readability/best practice for the way you did it - this is one place where is still just do `($result)`.